# Number Guesser game displays “-1 guesses left” just before the game refreshes and restarts

Tags: javascript, html

The game works fine, but for some reason it displays “-1 guesses left” when the game is over right after I click on the “play again” button and the game refreshes. The user only gets three guesses and the game should stop notifying guesses left after the remaining guesses are 0.

```js
  // guess btn handler
  guessBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // guess value
  let guess = parseInt(guessInput.value);

  // guess validator
  if (isNaN(guess) || guess < min || guess > max) {
    setMessage(`Please enter a number between ${min} and ${max}`, "red");
  } else if (guess === winningNum) {
    gameOver(true, `Winner! ${winningNum} is correct`);
    playAgain();
  } else {
    guessesLeft -= 1;
    
    if (guessesLeft === 0) {
      gameOver(false, `Game Over! ${winningNum} was the number`);
      playAgain();
    } else 

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Number Guesser</h1>
        <div id="game">
            <p>Guess a number between <span class="min-num"></span> and <span class="max-num"></span></p>
            <input type="number" id="guess-input" placeholder="Enter guess">
            <input type="submit" value="submit" id="guess-btn">
            <p class="message"></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    

<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

{
          setMessage(`${guessesLeft}  guesses left`, "red");
        }
      }
    });

```
// play again
function playAgain() {
  guessBtn.value = "Play Again";
  guessBtn.className += "play-again";
}

// game over
function gameOver(won, msgOutput) {
  let color;

  won === true ? color = "green" : color = "red";
  guessInput.disabled = true;
  guessInput.style.borderColor = color;
  setMessage(msgOutput, color);
}

// generate random winning number
function getRandomNum(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

// message box
function setMessage(msgOutput, color) {
  msg.style.color = color;
  msg.textContent = msgOutput;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Number Guesser</h1>
  <div id="game">
    <p>Guess a number between <span class="min-num"></span> and <span class="max-num"></span></p>
    <input type="number" id="guess-input" placeholder="Enter guess">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="guess-btn">
    <p class="message"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could we please have all of the code including `playAgain()`, `gameOver()` functions and the HTML markup.

Comment: Here is the rest of the code, My apologies  I'm still trying to figure all this out.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the below code. Here I've added some more code on play again button

```js
min=10;
max = 20;
winningNum = 13;
guessesLeft = 3;
// guess btn handler
const guessBtn = document.getElementById("guess-btn");
guessInput =  document.getElementById("guess-input");
const msg = document.getElementsByClassName("message")[0];
guessBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
 if(e.target.value === "submit"){
     // guess value
     let guess = parseInt(guessInput.value);
    
     // guess validator
     if (isNaN(guess) || guess < min || guess > max) {
       setMessage(`Please enter a number between ${min} and ${max}`, "red");
     } else if (guess === winningNum) {
       gameOver(true, `Winner! ${winningNum} is correct`);
       playAgain();
     } else {
       guessesLeft -= 1;
       
       if (guessesLeft === 0) {
         gameOver(false, `Game Over! ${winningNum} was the number`);
         playAgain();
       } else {
         setMessage(`${guessesLeft}  guesses left`, "red");
       }
     }
 }else{
     guessBtn.value = "submit";
     guessInput.value="";
     guessInput.disabled = false;
     guessInput.style.borderColor = "";
     setMessage("");
 }
 
});

// play again
function playAgain() {
  guessBtn.value = "Play Again";
  guessBtn.className += "play-again";
  guessesLeft = 3;
}

// game over
function gameOver(won, msgOutput) {
  let color;
  won === true ? color = "green" : color = "red";
  guessInput.disabled = true;
  guessInput.style.borderColor = color;
  setMessage(msgOutput, color);
}

// generate random winning number
function getRandomNum(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

// message box
function setMessage(msgOutput, color) {
  msg.style.color = color;
  msg.textContent = msgOutput;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React Boilerplate</title>



  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
  <h1>Number Guesser</h1>
  <div id="game">
    <p>Guess a number between <span class="min-num"></span> and <span class="max-num"></span></p>
    <input type="number" id="guess-input" placeholder="Enter guess">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="guess-btn">
    <p class="message"></p>
  </div>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```